# Sending parameter from parent to child window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about sending one extra parameter from parent browser window to pop up child, so far I have created this code.

Parent:

```
function addItem(id_value)
{
var newUrl = $('#add-'+id_value).attr('data-url');
var checkPort = $('#add-'+id_value).attr('id');

$('#add-'+id_value).click(function(){

    if(checkPort == 'add-fracht_1_pol_id' || checkPort == 'add-fracht_1_pod_id' || checkPort == 'add-fracht_2_pol_id' || 
       checkPort == 'add-fracht_2_pod_id' || checkPort == 'add-fracht_3_pol_id' || checkPort == 'add-fracht_3_pod_id')
    {
       window.opener.setParam(checkPort);
    }

    window.open(newUrl, 'newPerson', config='height=1500, width=1000, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes');

    return false;
});
}
```

Child:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var name = window.name;

var val = Boolean(false); 
var check = setParam(val);
alert(check);

if(name == 'newPerson')
{
    $('#save').remove();
    $('#save_stay').show();
    $('.form-actions').append('<input type="hidden" value="1" name="pop" />');
}    
else
{
    $('#save').show();
    $('#save_stay').remove();
}
});
```

But this does not and im stuck :(

Comment: You _can_ pass this data as an extra parameter in the URL? It's not the way you're trying to do it, but it's absolutely standard HTTP & guaranteed to work. (So long as the browser doesn't block your popup window, which would be a different issue.)

Answer (score 0):

> You can send any number of parameters by just appending to the url as GET parameters.

if the URL is something like this:

```
www.example.com/page.php
```

You can add parameters like this:

```
www.example.com/page.php?param=1
```

> This can be later accessed by PHP or JS

(PHP)

```
    if($_GET)
    echo $_GET['param'];
```

Comment: Matter of security I think, Im trying to send certain id, and don't want to people to mess with it .